# Linking on different version of shared libraries

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, g++

I have two versions of a a shared library:
**library version 2:**

simple.h

```
#pragma once
int first(int x);
```

simple.c

```
#include "simple.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__asm__(".symver first_1_0,first@LIBSIMPLE_1.0");
int first_1_0(int x)
{
    printf("lib: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return x + 1;
}

__asm__(".symver first_2_0,first@@LIBSIMPLE_2.0");
int first_2_0(int x)
{
    int y;
    printf("lib: %d\n", y);
    printf("lib: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return (x + 1) * 1000;
}
```

linker version script file:

```
LIBSIMPLE_1.0{
    global:
    first;
    local:
    *;
};

LIBSIMPLE_2.0{
    global:
    first;
    local:
    *;
};

gcc -Wall -g -O0 -fPIC -c simple.c
gcc -shared simple.o -Wl,--version-script,script -o libsimple.so.2.0.0
```

**And library version 3:**

simple.h

```
#pragma once  
#ifdef SIMPLELIB_VERSION_3_0
int first(int x, int normfactor);
#else
int first(int x);
#endif //SIMPLELIB_VERSION_3_0
```

simple.c

```
#include "simple.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__asm__(".symver first_1_0,first@LIBSIMPLE_1.0");
int first_1_0(int x)
{
    printf("lib: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return x + 1;
}

__asm__(".symver first_2_0,first@LIBSIMPLE_2.0");
int first_2_0(int x)
{
    printf("lib: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return (x + 1) * 1000;
}

__asm__(".symver first_3_0,first@@LIBSIMPLE_3.0");
int first_3_0(int x, int normfactor)
{
    printf("lib: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return (x + 1) * normfactor;
}
```

Linker version script file:

```
LIBSIMPLE_1.0{
    global:
    first; second;
    local:
    *;
};

LIBSIMPLE_2.0{
    global:
    first;
    local:
    *;
};

LIBSIMPLE_3.0{
    global:
    first;
    local:
    *;
};

gcc -Wall -g -O0 -fPIC -c simple.c
gcc -shared simple.o -Wl,--version-script,script -o libsimple.so.3.0.0
```

So i end up with having two different libraries. Next i create a simple application, that eventually i want to link to a library version 3, so in it i use function first() that takes two arguments:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simple.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int nFirst = first(1, 10);
    printf("First(1) = %d\n", nFirst);
}
```

I compile app with next commands:

```
gcc -g -Wall -DSIMPLELIB_VERSION_3_0 -c main.c
```

And then, by accident, instead of linking to a library version 3, i linked against library version 2. I expected linking to fail, but it went through, and application was working.

```
gcc main.o -Wl,-L. -lsimple.2.0.0 -Wl,-R. -o demo
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it because library exports symbol with name 'function', and application tries to link to the same symbol name, and that is why linker didn't complain, and just linked against library version 2 ?
2. I thought since c++ mangles symbol names, such thing wouldn't happen, and linker wouldn't link to a library version 2. So i tried all the same, but instead of a gcc compiler, i tried to use g++. Everything went well, until i tried to link application to a library, and i received unresolved links error. Can not figure out why.

p.s. Sorry for a big amount of code. I was trying to make it clear.
Thanks

Comment: Im closing this question. First part of it i understand, and for the second part i will create new more specific question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because library exports symbol with name 'function', and application tries to link to the same symbol name, and that is why linker didn't complain, and just linked against library version 2 ?

Yes, since plain C does not have function overload there is no need for mangling and as a consequence only function name will be used as a symbol for linking. In the end your *application code* wants to link with `function` and your *library code* exports `function` and this is enough to keep linker happy (even though it is not valid from binary interface perspective).

> I thought since c++ mangles symbol names, such thing wouldn't happen, and linker wouldn't link to a library version 2. So i tried all the same, but instead of a gcc compiler, i tried to use g++. Everything went well, until i tried to link application to a library, and i received unresolved links error. Can not figure out why.

Yes, this problem should not occur in C++ because of name mangling. However, this is true only if you have both your *application code* and *library code* in C++ or if you bridge your C and C++ code the right way.

It is hard to say (without full listing) what happened in your case when you used g++ but from the looks of it you ended up having *application code* in C++ and *library code* still in C. If that is the case your *application code* will now want to link with mangled `function` while your *library code* still exports unmangled `function`.

To verify this you can inspect your object file with something like:

```
nm main.o
```

... and see exactly what kind of symbol does it want. If you will get something like this:

```
...
    U _Z3functionii
...
```

... instead of:

```
...
    U function
...
```

... then that is the case.

To "fix" this and make your C++ *application code* link with unmangled `function` from *library code* you'll need to declare your function prototype as `extern "C"`.